# create a function that returns a function that behaves in the same way as the passed in function

Tags: typescript, function, generics

I'm trying to create a function that accepts a function as a param and returns a function that that behaves in the same way as the passed in function (as the core of some more complex business logic).

```
// a function that returns a function that behaves
// in the same way as the passed in function.
export function create<T extends Function>(func: T): T {
  function run(...args: any[]) {
    // Later I plan on doing some stuff here...
    return func(...args);
    // ...and here
  }
  return run;
}

const source = (n:number) =>  n.toString();
const created = create(source);
```

The above code works and I get the correct type annotation and completion  on `created()` (`const created: (n: number) => string`) but typescript is complaining that

> Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> '(...args: any[]) => any' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Function'.

This message is a bit impenetrable to me. Could you help me understand it and suggest some ways that I could solve this issue? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with a call signature like

```
function create<T extends Function>(func: T): T { /* ✂ ⋯ ✂ */ }
```

is that it claims to return a value of exactly the same type as the `func` input, no matter what.  [Functions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) are first-class objects and can also have properties like any other object.  So you can do this:

```
const source = (n: number) => n.toString();
source.prop = "hello";
/* const source: {
  (n: number): string;
  prop: string;
} */
```

Here `source` is a function with a string-valued `prop` property.  But your implementation of `create()` doesn't try to make sure that every property of `func` is copied to the output.  So the compiler warns you that while your returned function is definitely a `Function`, it might not be a `T`.  If you ignore that error then the following problem can happen:

```
const created = create(source);
console.log(created(123)) // "123", this is good
try {
  console.log(created.prop.toUpperCase()) // no compiler error, but
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e) //  RUNTIME ERROR: created.prop is undefined
}
```

The compiler will happily allow you to access `create.prop` because `create(source)` supposedly returns something exactly like `create`.  And you get a runtime error.  Oops.

---

The conventional way to do what you're doing is to explicitly care only about the call signature of the input and not the whole input type: that is, you want the function to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the list of argument types `A` and the return type `R`:

```
function create<A extends any[], R>(func: (...args: A) => R): (...args: A) => R {
  function run(...args: A) {
    return func(...args);
  }
  return run; // okay
}
```

This now compiles without error.  You can still pass functions with extra properties into `create()`, but now the output value doesn't pretend to have such extra properties, so you get a compiler error, which will help you avoid the runtime error:

```
const source = (n: number) => n.toString();
source.prop = "hello"; 
const created = create(source);
console.log(created(123)) // "123" // this is good
created.prop; // compiler error 
//      ~~~~
// Property 'prop' does not exist on type '(n: number) => string'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIByA9gC4BKAlgOYAWdeRJJA9L0hBIAZgFdg8OkxrAkdNiE4AnCHVFLgUQSPGTps+YqQAjCAoBu0bj35ImBtsijhkAdxABPQVvnI4UKAgAEztZMQkpGQA6axJwvRkkeBVFCAAeABUkCAAPOghgIK0AMV1I4AA+AAp4gC4kDIBKeqyCYh44sv0kJXEqqIGQJRYoepBgDwBtAF1GrnaOvgEAGVSlJABJJBgMcaREoJp7FiQoGkhTtWFhJEcVAZiFxZU1DR0JfsHhqEaAbljFrYHuMQncIACSABfCE9VTqWS9YD-J7QwgA+AyKCcM7qRBIAC8SCqwHqwFEYFMSjm+IqpCidBoAGU6EpjlU-gCcUpEFEYEoaDACUgAESODAYGjC5EdXgAKiSmOxNFxEHqbUWRJJpHJlOal1ZwBY0sWfIF9SxBqNAMhSFlvHRiqSKXyIUJyQgqSqXMQHKeGM0NAwECiEpYVXdqSCVQAjAAmADMjTmtmFcfjwoBLK86sW-rOQZDNDDEZdvP5MHpNAAqjAYBAlABhECBdnJgTAGgKsAwJhB9b1-lKAA0JlEdGtSUU8DYRIgcxzHTzgeDoaqc6QtkAvBuAUp2kAwq1QMhsALIAUSQp4YDAA8gx6iXgmWBXYtOIghBhPZgtaiNZUSQyGgOA8WYdhODaAFbCEeJyjkBRlDhDQtGgrpEkMThTAsKwnlsew4KcFwkHcLxm3w7Zm0CEI8Jg-RHg6GjEgfNIAEFsjyAoikECYZhHBhqjqIlgW+epmOpWkGD1T4oiGEYRLEvd5g1BiET6ITZKQUTFI1DcVjWTZtl2WQDiOQ1TnOJwrhuMEHhhEgXnhd54CkmSfmNDUgUGQpbnrcEnihGF7LeRE3KQf8eDzJUVSFYlSR1et5OAStmUtdkQu9YNTUFQlRQgcVJRCiKnQ9F0hQfL1lW5OcCsxZdC2LZ1ghjBMkx0kU0wzP0GqCJ8YF+VqMW7Xt62yJRByQSCBEWAA-GapompAAAVy3rOgvAAckytakEOaBSHoNimCxfYDA8OskDWmLtQpeKCVpC1jjWv8iEhIA)

Comment: This is such a clear and well written answer that really helped me understand what is happening and how to fix the code. Much appreciated @jcalz!